# How to provide a copy constructor for the overloaded lambda trick

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, overloading

I have the following code which extends the *overload* trick with lambda to also accept a variant. However the variant is not the issue in the example.

https://godbolt.org/z/GxhaPr

```
#include <memory>
#include <variant>
#include <functional>

template <class ...Fs>
struct overload : Fs... {
    template <class ...Ts>
    overload(Ts&& ...ts) : Fs{std::forward<Ts>(ts)}...
    {} 
    using Fs::operator()...;

    template <class ...Vs>
    auto operator()(std::variant<Vs...>&&arg){
        return std::visit(*this,std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
    }

};

template <typename ...Ts>
overload(Ts&&...) -> overload<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>...>;

using Foo = std::variant<int, char*, double,long>;

int main()
{
    
    auto fn = overload(
                [](int x){ return 0;}
                ,[](char * x) {return 1;}
                ,[](double x){ return 2;}
                ,[](long x){ return 3;}
    );

    std::function<int(Foo)> fn2 = overload(
                [&](auto x){return fn(x);}
    );

    //auto ff = fn;
    //std::function<int(Foo)> fn3 = fn;

    auto a = fn2(10);
    auto b = fn2((char *)"10");
    auto c = fn2(10.);

    auto d = fn(10);
    auto e = fn((char *)"10");
    auto f = fn(10.);

    return a+b+c+d+e+f;
}
```

which works fine. But if I uncomment the line

```
auto ff=fn;
```

then the code fails because the default copy constructor for `overload` does not work. Is it possible to write one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code fails to compile is not because `overload`'s default copy constructor doesn't work. It's because the templated constructor is basically a catch-all. Any and every constructor argument will match it, so it will always get called.

You can use some SFINAE on the `overload` constructor to make sure it doesn't get called for copy/move construction:

```
template <class ...Fs>
struct overload : Fs... {
    template <class ...Ts, std::enable_if_t<
        (sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(Fs))
        and (std::is_same_v<Fs, std::remove_reference_t<Ts>> && ...)
      , int> = 0>
    overload(Ts&& ...ts) : Fs{std::forward<Ts>(ts)}...
    {} 
    
    // Rest of existing overload code goes here.
};
```

Note that I'm not really sure whether the conditions I used in that `std::enable_if` are entirely correct, but I think they make sense here. And they make your example compile, so...

A link to the solution code on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Tzn9f3.

Comment: It's really a bug in the C++ language spec that the syntax for move and forwarding references are identical and only differentiated by the factor that the type is a template parameter. If there was a ``&&&`` forwarding reference operator then the constructor could be declared as ``overload(Fs&&&...fs) : Fs{std::forward<Fs>(fs)}...`` *note usage of Fs not Ts*.  I've never really understood this oversight given the pain it causes.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that this is quite annoying behavior that a constructor like this can override the copy/move constructor. Alternatively they could have made it such that you always have to explicitly override them, but I'm sure that would open a whole other can of worms :).